# How to find binomial pmf with probability = another random variable

Tags: probability, functions, random

Assume that $Q$ is a random variable with density proportional to $q$ for $0 < q < 1$. Given $Q = q$, $N$ has a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $q$.

What is the probability mass function of $N$?

Answer (score 2):

If $Q$ has density $f$ on $[0,1]$ and if, conditionally on $Q=q$, $N$ has conditional probability mass function $p(\ \mid q)$, then Bayes formula yields
$$
P(N=k)=\int_0^1P(N=k\mid Q=q)\,f(q)\,\mathrm dq=\int_0^1p(k\mid q)\,f(q)\,\mathrm dq.
$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Yes, thanks - didn't think of using Bayes formula

Comment: Isn't the equation you wrote more accurately described as the law of total probability, or the definition of marginal probability?  Bayes' theorem/rule is more like $$f_{Q \mid N}(q) = \frac{\Pr[N = k \mid Q = q] f_Q(q)}{\Pr[N = k]},$$ no?

Comment: @heropup Possibly. Thanks for the input.